# Select SUM using Multiple Criteria in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Command that sums a data and Sad to say its a Varchar.

here is my command

```
SELECT SUM(replace(TotalAmount, ',', ''))
FROM physicalinv_final
WHERE ItemCode LIKE 'DRY%' AND
      PINo = 'PI00000001'
```

The output of that is to sum up `TotalAmount` where `ItemCode` contains the word **DRY** and `PINo` = PI00000001

My question is like this I have also other criteria like this

```
BEV
DES
MEA
OTH
DRY
RIC
SEA
```

I try this code

`SELECT SUM(replace(TotalAmount, ',', '')) FROM physicalinv_final where ItemCode like 'DRY%' ItemCode like 'BEV%' and So On ..... and PINo = 'PI00000001'`

but the output is `null` although i have a data that contains **DRY**.

this the output i want

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrSgU.png)

is there a way to fix this?

TYSM for help

Comment: Can you post some examples of `TotalAmount`?

Comment: Sure sir pls wait for my edited post

Comment: @tomb I'm _guessing_ (just a guess) that the `TotalAmount` is some figure which has commas in it.  He is trying to remove the commas, and then let MySQL figure out the appropriate cast to be used in `SUM`.

Comment: youre right sir Pls see the edited post

Comment: You have 2 solutions below that appear to produce your desired results.  What's wrong with them?

Comment: Already accepted as answer TY for all of the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `or` and `group by` instead:

```
SELECT ItemCode, SUM(replace(TotalAmount, ',', '')) 
FROM physicalinv_final 
WHERE (ItemCode like 'DRY%' OR 
      ItemCode like 'BEV%' OR ...) 
    AND PINo = 'PI00000001'
GROUP BY ItemCode
```

---

Or if you just want the overall `sum` containing any of those item codes, remove the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(replace(TotalAmount, ',', '')) 
FROM physicalinv_final 
WHERE (ItemCode like 'DRY%' OR 
      ItemCode like 'BEV%' OR ...) 
    AND PINo = 'PI00000001'
```

Comment: @ShadowFiend -- these queries produce your expected results.  The first groups by item and the second returns the sum.  Use them both or `union` them together.  your expected results are in excel format and a little unclear...

Comment: @sgeddes His order of operations in the`WHERE` clause might have been causing no results to come back.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- agreed, the parentheses with or appear to be what the OP was after.  I tried to make that clear in my answer -- your edits look to have made our answers the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sir sorry for not clearing it out i will edit it again sir. Meanwhile please see sgeddes answer for enlightenment